# Python script that leaves an activated virtualenv after it halts

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv

I'm trying to create a utility CLI that creates an empty python project with just a .venv inside.

One of the features I wanted is that, when the CLI ends the project creation, it leaves the bash inside the project folder and with the virtualenv activated. This way:

```sh
(base) ubuntu@pc:~/dev/cli$ python cli.py start ./folder

        ... do it's magic ...

        ... and ends up like this:
(.venv) ubuntu@pc:~/dev/cli/folder$
```

Note that now the **cwd** is inside **folder**  and **(.venv) ** is activated.

I was able to achieve part of my objective (change the folder) by using:

```py
import os

os.chdir("./folder")
os.execl("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash")
```

But didn't find a way to keep the venv activated after the program is halted.

Any ideas??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+activate+from+script

Comment: `/bin/bash -c ". ../.env/bin/activate; exec /bin/bash -i"`

Comment: that didn't work for me @phd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` has the `-rcfile` option that allows to use a non standard initialization file.

```
import os

os.chdir("./folder")
os.execl("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash", "--rcfile", ".venv/bin/activate")
```

That should be enough for the new `.venv` to be active in the `bash` shell.

Comment: Thank you that worked! 

A detail is that with this implementation, the bash returns very raw, without the usual ubuntu terminal syntax highlighting. Any clues about it?

Comment: @VittorFaria: by default `bash` reads the `.bashrc` file. Here it reads `bin/activate` **instead** of its default initialization file.